# Using @ConfigurationProperties to override an application.yml property isn't working, isn't it straightforward?

Tags: spring, spring-boot-starter, configurationproperties

I thought / hoped that overriding property values using ConfigurationProperties would be as easy as reading them, but it isn't, so I feel like I'm missing something trivial as right now I have a JavaFX application with different screens in which I can read and use properties that are in the application.yml, but one of the screens is a "support" screen where some admin should come when logging on and they should be able to change the values in the application.yml

I cannot find what I'm doing wrong as I do see the setter being called when I change something in the support screen but the application.yml stays unchanged :-/

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ConfigProperties {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigProperties.class);

    String deviceId;

    String resolution;

    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public String getResolution() {
        return resolution;
    }

    public void setResolution(String resolution) {
        this.resolution = resolution;
        LOGGER.debug("resolution set to {}", resolution);
    }
```

screen controller

```
    public void btnSaveClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        btnSave.setDisable(true);
        configProperties.setDeviceId(txtDevice.getText());
        configProperties.setResolution(txtResolution.getText());
    }
```

in the pom the only spring references are spring-boot-starter and spring-boot-autoconfigure, both 2.7.4

Comment: I don't think that @ConfigurationProperties annotation provides write property functionality. It is by design read-only and allows you to read properties but not override them.
I haven't heard of any standard Spring feature that allows you to write application.yaml.

You should reconsider storing custom configuration in a different place than application.yaml, as it is not designed to provide such functionality.

Comment: Ah, okay. I do have an old project that uses the ini-file reader / writer from org.ini4j, but in the mvnrepository I see that that library is not updated anymore after 2015 so that feels obsolete, I'll look for something a bit more up to date ...